# Defining functions in a CDF and Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, cdf-format, deployment

I want to deploy an interactive CDF that may depend on several functions. How do I define those functions? I'm using `Manipulate`, I defined the function inside it prior to returning the value I want, that is

```
CDFDeploy["test01",
 Manipulate[
  f = Function[x, x^2];
  f[z],
  {z, 0, 10}]]
```

This indeed yields what I want

[image]

I have, however, a few questions:

- Is there a better way of defining functions to be used within a CDF? I wonder if it can be more efficient. For example, defining `f` before `Manipulate` doesn't work.
- When I try to use, for example, `f[x_] := x^2`, the notebook starts to blink and freezes. Any idea why?
- I've been mostly using `Manipulate`, but I've also heard of `DynamicModule` for interactive CDFs. I'm not very acquainted with it. Could it be useful in my case?

Comment: Define inside using Initialization or outside using SaveDefinitions.

Comment: Great! I've added an answer for the record, based on your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment by Kuba ♦ in the comment section, using `Initialization` solves my problem

```
CDFDeploy["test01",
 Manipulate[
  f[z],
  {z, 0, 10},
  Initialization :> (f[x_] := x^2)]]
```